# Conditions on one forms

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am trying to solve exercise 8.3 from Lightman's problem book, but I don't know where to start to get a sufficient and necessary condition on a field of one forms $\tilde\sigma$ for there to exist a function f such that $\tilde\sigma $ = $\tilde{df}$.

I even tried to understand the solution, but I didn't. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Math Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. For clarity, the question refers to 3-dimensional Euclidean space.

Let $f$ be a scalar function that is at least two times continuously differentiable. It is important to note ${\bf \tilde\sigma}$ is a $1$-form field.
The scalar function $f$ is said to be a $0$-form. If we can write

$$
{\bf \tilde \sigma} = \tilde{df} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dy\,.
$$

we can say ${\bf \tilde\sigma}$ is exact.

By the Poincare Lemma we can say that exterior derivative of ${\bf \tilde\sigma}$ vanishes, i.e.,

$$
d(\tilde{df}) = 0\,.
$$

But the exterior derivative of $\tilde \sigma$ is

$$
d\tilde\sigma  = \left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\right)dx \wedge dy +\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial z} - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial x}\right)dx \wedge dz + \left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial z} - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial y}\right)dy \wedge dz\,.
$$

Since $d\tilde\sigma = 0$ it must be the case that

$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}\,,\quad 
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial z} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial x}\,,\quad 
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial z} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z\partial y}\,.
$$

This is exactly the condition that is meant by $\sigma_{i,j} = \sigma_{j,i}\,$ as Lightman et al. suggest in their solution because

$$
\tilde\sigma_{i} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{i}}\,,
$$
where $i=1,2,3$ and $x^1=x, x^2 = y, x^3=z\,.$

I didn't use the content at the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form but I think exact differential forms are mentioned there. I checked "Tensors, Differential Forms and Variational Principles" by David Lovelock and Hanno Rund.

Comment: The answer is in fact discussed at the link I reference. See the section entitled "Differential Calculus" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Differential_calculus

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very well explained!

Comment: I am glad to help!

Comment: Just one more question, shouldn't $\tilde\sigma$ be a closed differential form to use Poincaré Lemma? According to the book that you used, a exact differential form has exterior derivative different than zero.

Comment: As far as I am aware, a differential form, e.g. a $p$-form, $\tilde\sigma$, is said to be $exact$ when it can be written as the exterior derivative of a $(p-1)$-form, $\pi$. This means we can write 

$$
\tilde\sigma = d\pi\,.
$$

Poincare's Lemma states that every exact $p$-form is closed. Since $\tilde\sigma$ is exact if it can written as $\tilde\sigma = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^{i}$. If $f$ is a function that is at least twice continiuously differentiable it follows that $\tilde{d\sigma}=0$. See Chapter 5 sections 2 & 3, formulae 2.6, 2.8, 3.1 and 3.2 of the book I reference.

Comment: I hope this helps. Thanks for accepting my answer and the upvote. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you very much!